# Get year of current year

Tags: mysql, date, fetch

```
SELECT DISTINCT(toda) toda, count(DISTINCT toda) as numusers 
FROM tbl_complains WHERE YEAR(dates)= YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY toda ORDER BY toda
```

I'm trying to get only the data of this year but my "WHERE CLAUSE" seems to have a problem. But when I input a specific year on the where clause, it's working. Everything is working except the where clause.

I hope you guys can help me with this.

Comment: What is `DISTINCT(toda)`? DISTINCT is not a function, remove it. `WHERE YEAR(dates)= YEAR(NOW())` is correct.

Comment: Can you give an example for where it does not work.

Comment: Everything works fine except for my where clause. When I do WHERE YEAR(dates) = 2021 it works. But =YEAR(NOW()) it doesnt show anything.

Comment: Btw, =YEAR(NOW()) works in my other queries. This one is the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very bad idea to calculate some things in where clase of a field. MySQL must calculate this on each row to see if the use the ROW for the result.
This give a FULL TABLE SCAN and can be slow

Better use

```
SELECT DISTINCT(toda) toda, count(DISTINCT toda) as numusers 
FROM tbl_complains 
WHERE dates BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') 
                AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-12-31'))
GROUP BY toda ORDER BY toda;
```

So MySQL must only calculate the dates one time and can also use a index if there one

Comment: 'my "WHERE CLAUSE" seems to have a problem.' - You are guessing the problem is performance? Fair enough given op doesn't say...